# Computing the quotient and remainder of two numbers using the successor representation in prolog

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

This is what I have using the predicates, plus and greater_than. However, I wanted to implement this using predicates, times and plus.

```
plus(0, N, N).
plus(s(M), N, s(P)) :-
   plus(M, N, P).

greater_than(X, Y) :-
   plus(Y, Z, X),
   Z \= 0.

qr(A, B, 0, A) :-
   greater_than(B, A).
qr(A, B, Q, R) :-
   plus(C, B, A), 
   qr(C, B, T, R),
   plus(s(0), T, Q).
```

PS:

```
times(O,X,O).
times(s(X),Y,Z) :-
   times(X,Y,XY),
   plus(XY,Y,Z).
```

Comment: @lurker Write a program for computing the quotient and remainder of two numbers using the successor representation

Comment: You realize that for "greater than", you can use pattern matching and unification like this: `plus(X, s(_), Y)` (so now Y must be greater than X since you added a non-zero to it). Anyway, have you decided which algorithm you want to use for this? It would be easier to help if you identified an algorithm and tried to implement it first, you can ask a more specific question then.